# Correct Phone number format for stripe connect create customer

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a stripe connect customer using node.js. However, every time I make the request it gives me an "invalid phone number" error.

I've already tried several different phone numbers and formats.

- "+10000000000"
- "0000000000"
- "+1000-000-0000"
- "000-000-0000"

```
    const opts: any = {
                            type: 'custom',
                            country: 'US',
                            email: user.email,
                            business_type: 'individual',
                            business_profile:{
                                url: 'www.blulight.tech'
                            },
                            individual:{
                                phone: user.phoneNumber,
                                email: user.email,
                                first_name: user.name.firstName,
                                last_name: user.name.lastName,
                                dob: {
                                    day: user.dateOfBirth.day,
                                    month: user.dateOfBirth.month,
                                    year: user.dateOfBirth.year
                                },
                                address:{
                                    line1: user.address.line1,
                                    line2: user.address.line2,
                                    postal_code: user.address.postal_code,
                                    city: user.address.city,
                                    state: user.address.state
                                },
                                ssn_last_4: user.dateOfBirth.ssn_last_4,
                                verification: {
                                    document:{
                                        back:  documents[1].id,
                                        front:  documents[0].id,
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            tos_acceptance: {
                                date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                                ip: user.ipAddress
                            }
                        };
```

> ```
> Not a valid phone number
>     at Function.generate (/srv/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:49:16)
>     at IncomingMessage.res.once (/srv/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:167:39)
>     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
>     at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
> ```

Comment: What is the value of `user.phoneNumber` in this case?  Are you sure it's what you expect it to be?  Did you look at the Request in the Dashboard to see what it looked like?  What's the complete error message you're getting from Stripe?

Comment: i have tried several different values for user.phoneNumber  "+10000000000" "0000000000" "+1000-000-0000" "000-000-0000" none of these formats work however the stripe node js api has the individual.phone as a string

Comment: Still no answer to this? I'm having the same issue,

Comment: It looks like they expect a valid US number. I was able to make it work using "2015550123" after seeing it buried in this page: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing-verification. However, I don't know how to make it validate a different country code... Zero documentation about this online.

Comment: Yep, looks like it's not supporting test inputs for phone number validation. Had to give it a real number to make it work...

Answer (score 2):

You probably already solved the issue but there is no answer. I found that what works best is full international number i.e. '+49 89 416115623'.

I am using libphonenumber-js and its parsePhoneNumberFromString method:

const parsedPhoneNumber = parsePhoneNumberFromString(phoneNumber);
parsedPhoneNumber.formatInternational();

which outputs just the number listed above.

Comment: Does this library work for IOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the test account creation with stripe connect where I found the test phone number. You can find more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing-verification).

[image: Image of person creation]

Comment: This does not help at all, the format in the exemple does not event work.

Answer (score 0):

The phone number must be 10 characters long and not start with a `0`.

Comment: less than 11 digits + '+' test Stripe API cosider not a valid number, like '+1555123456' and '+15551234560' is ok